# When I change theme, I can't see my sidebars

Tags: 7, theming

I am a total n00b, just trying to set up my first site.

I got something nice with the Bartik theme, then realized that I wanted drop-down menus on the main menu, so decided to try another theme.

I tried both Corolla and Martinelli, but when I set them as default theme I can't see my sidebars or footers.

The are still set up as they were for Bartik and if I switch back to that then I see them again.

Obviously, this is just some stupid n00b thing, like not knowing to rebuild the front page or something. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. No matter which themes I activate, under "admin/structure/block" only the BARTIK and SEVEN tabs are showing up. Even if I disable BARTIK, it's shown. I can't configure the blocks for my theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because themes haven't the same region names, after changing your theme you must go to *admin/structure/block* and re-assign blocks to regions.

Comment: I thought it must be something like that. But when I go there I only see tabs for Bartik and Seven, not for either of the two themes which I added. Any idea how I administer Martinelli or Coralla?  They do appear to be installed correctly, as they are in the list of themes under admin/appearance and if I set one as default, the site layout changes - but I can't see those blocks and I can't see how to administer them.  Heeeeeelp

Comment: +1 thanks. Hope you can help further withmy comment above

Comment: @Mawg: First clear cache from here: admin/config/development/performance

Comment: +1 Thnaks. Another good tip, but unfrotunaely it did not work. Can it be that I have the themes "half installed? That is - modules won't install without their dependancis, but maybe themes will? Maybe I should read the relaease notes agin, just to be sure

Comment: Strange!! I had given up on this and just went back to that page a week or two later and saw that it now works. Maybe some of the updates, or disabling a few modules to try to speed it up, or updating drupal core? In any case, it suddenly works and I don't know why.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin/structure/blocks. The tabs at the upper right of the form allow you to select your theme.  arranging the blocks in one them does not change them in every theme so you must Verify their location in the new themes. You should find the missing blocks at the bottom of the form in the 'Disabled' category.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to reply. I will try that later and get back to you. Pelase check this question anagin in 8 hours or so. Thanks.

Comment: My problem seems to be that I can see tabs at the top of Admin/structure/blocks for Bartik and Seven, but not for Corolla or Martinalli.  Coudl it be that they are not completely and correctly installed? Although they do show up in the list of themes under admin/appearance

Comment: If your themes are enabled on the admin/appearance form they should show up in block tabs.  Where in the site directory do you have them?  Each should be in a subdirectory under sites/all/themes/...

Comment: +1 sorry about the delay. I think we are in very different time zones (I am GMT +8).  Since I installed them both by giving the URL of the initial release I would not expect problems (just my bad luck, I suppose). Yes, I can confirm that there are directories named for the themes where you think they should be. And, yes, the themes are enabled.    I will go and RTFM again

Comment: I'm GMT-5. What is RTFM?

Comment: so, we are almost opposite each other on the clock.   RTFM == read the "friendly" manual. And I still can't see those themes in the tabs of Admin/structure/blocks - even though they are installed (from the URL) and enabled